# .Net Core 2.2 API in Linux Service with SSL (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: systemd, ssl

I have a .Net Core 2.2 API that has been tested and working when launched from a linux command shell (Ubuntu 16.04) but when run as a service only http is bound, not https. I know this is more likely due to service environment needing to be told about SSL but I have not found any information on how to set this up in the service unit file. Any help would be appreciated.

Service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Authentication .NET Web API App running on CentOS 7

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/Authentication
ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /var/www/Authentication/Authentication.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-authentication
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Console Output:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /var/www/Authentication
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

systemctl status:

```
● Authentication.service - Authentication .NET Web API App running on CentOS 7
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Authentication.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-07-22 06:48:36 CDT; 38min ago
 Main PID: 11506 (dotnet)
   CGroup: /system.slice/Authentication.service
           └─11506 /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /var/www/Authentication/Authentication.dll

Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]:       Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]:       No XML encryptor configured. Key {bc217aa5-1a54-4033-bcb3-0d1bd39cf425} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]:       Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Hosting environment: Production
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Content root path: /var/www/Authentication
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

journalctl Output:

```
Jul 22 06:48:36 Chris-PC systemd[1]: Started Authentication .NET Web API App running on CentOS 7.
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: : Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]:       Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]:       Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
Jul 22 06:48:38 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]:       No XML encryptor configured. Key {bc217aa5-1a54-4033-bcb3-0d1bd39cf425} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]:       Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Hosting environment: Production
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Content root path: /var/www/Authentication
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Jul 22 06:48:40 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[11506]: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue is related to www-data user id. If I edit service unit to use my id (id run under command shell) then both http and https are bound. Need to figure out what is diffrent with ww-data.

systemctl status:

```
● Authentication.service - Authentication .NET Web API App running on CentOS 7
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Authentication.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-07-22 08:17:05 CDT; 8min ago
 Main PID: 19440 (dotnet)
   CGroup: /system.slice/Authentication.service
           └─19440 /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /var/www/Authentication/Authentication.dll

Jul 22 08:17:05 Chris-PC systemd[1]: Started Authentication .NET Web API App running on CentOS 7.
Jul 22 08:17:10 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Jul 22 08:17:10 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]:       Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
Jul 22 08:17:11 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Jul 22 08:17:11 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]:       Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
Jul 22 08:17:11 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]: Hosting environment: Production
Jul 22 08:17:11 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]: Content root path: /var/www/Authentication
Jul 22 08:17:11 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Jul 22 08:17:11 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]: Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Jul 22 08:17:11 Chris-PC dotnet-authentication[19440]: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```